ASP.NET Core 7 MVC : adding more detail, attributes, or something to extend exception handler page
I'm using the exception handler page as described in the provided link. However the ExceptionHandlerPathFeature doesn't provide all the details I'd like to use. This app is an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application, so it's a Web UI, with web pages, etc. When a page is displayed, it's displayed from a controllers action building a model and then providing a View (aka the page).
When unhandled exceptions are thrown from a page, what I'd like to be able to do is get the model and view details of the page (aka view), though in reality the controller, that threw the error.
For example...
If I have a Privacy view, I then have a Privacy web page. When a user loads the Privacy web page, the PrivacyController's Index action creates a Privacy model, then creates a Privacy view loaded with that model. The Privacy view is then returned.
However from a business perspective, the Privacy page is referred to as the "Corporate Privacy Compliance Page".
If the Index action of the PrivacyController throws an unhandled exception, I want to be able to provide a message:

An error occurred with the Corporate Privacy Compliance Page

How can I add some kind of attribute or something to the PrivacyController (or anywhere else), that will trickle up to the ExceptionHandlerPathFeature so that I can dynamically pull name "Corporate Privacy Compliance Page" as opposed to "Privacy", which is all that I get from the ExceptionHandlerPathFeature.Path or ExceptionHandlerPathFeature.RouteValues attributes?
Ideally, I'd like to put a DisplayName attribute on all of my controllers and have that DisplayName attribute trickle up to the ExceptionHandlerPathFeature when an exception occurs.
Example:
[DisplayName("Corporate Privacy Compliance Page")]
public class PrivacyController: Controller


According to your description, you could create a custom exception handler to get the display attribute details and then pass to the error action.
More details, you could refer to below example codes:
1.Display attribute:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DisplayNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string DisplayName { get; }

    public DisplayNameAttribute(string displayName)
    {
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }
}

2.CustomExceptionHandler
public class CustomExceptionHandler : IAsyncExceptionFilter
{
    public async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // Check if the exception is handled
        if (context.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Get the controller type
        var displayNameAttribute =context.ActionDescriptor?.EndpointMetadata.Where(x=>x.GetType() == typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();



        if (displayNameAttribute == null)
        {
            return;
        }

      


        var displayName = ((DisplayNameAttribute)displayNameAttribute).DisplayName ?? "Unknown";


        var errorMessage = $"An error occurred with the {displayName}";


        context.HttpContext.Items["ErrorMessage"] = errorMessage;

        // Mark the exception as handled
        context.ExceptionHandled = false;
    }
}

3.Add the handler to the controller method in program.cs:
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<CustomExceptionHandler>();
});

4.Use it in error :
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {

        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
      HttpContext.Items["ErrorMessage"];

        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }

5.home controller:
[DisplayName("Corporate Privacy Compliance Page")]
public class HomeController : Controller

Result:

